# curl pass the pass phrase along with command line

Tags: curl

I am using following command:

```
curl -X GET -k --header "Accept: text/plain" --key privateKey.pem --cert publicCert.pem --cacert ca.crt "https://example.org/update"
```

after I execute this command, system ask me to enter the pass phrase:

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

How can I pass phrase along with command line so no manual intervention is required.

Comment: There are two ways, adding it to `--cert` or using `--pass`. Both are described in the man page [online here if your system is broken](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and in general the man page for a program almost always describes how to use that program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as suggested by @dave adding **--pass** did the trick

```
curl -X GET -k --header "Accept: text/plain" --key privateKey.pem --cert publicCert.pem --cacert ca.crt "https://example.org/update" --pass myPassword
```